# Read large csv file with non-standard timestamp column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to read a csv file with data like this:

```
data.csv:

time,value
12/31/2015 7:00:00 PM,275.9271
12/31/2015 7:00:02 PM,278.559
12/31/2015 7:00:10 PM,277.5949
12/31/2015 7:00:12 PM,270.0564
```

My problem is that there is a lot of data and if I try to read the file while telling the reader to parse the time column like:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates = ['time'])
```

It is very slow.  If on the other hand I read the data, and then try to convert the time column, it is also slow:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.time)
```

After looking around the web, the solution seems to be to specify the format of the time, but this fails because the months and hours are missing zero-padding:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.time,format='%b/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')
```

> ValueError: time data '10/26/2016 7:00:01 PM' does not match format '%b/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p' (match)

Is there a way to make a format string to match non-standard data?  Or else to speed up one of the auto-recognition methods?  Thank you!

Comment: Your seconds _are_ zero padded. And your example months 10 and 12 will never be zero padded. In any case, strptime will attempt to parse even if the expected zero padding is missing.

Comment: You are right, I meant to say hours, I will edit the question

Comment: In most cases strptime will get it right whether there's padding spaces or not. An exception are datestamps with no separators which are inherently ambiguous.  For example: `1012017` could mean either `1/01/2017` or `10/1/2017` or even maybe `10/12/017`. But humans also fail to parse those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `%b` should be `%m`?

> `%b`  Month as locale’s abbreviated name.
>
> `%m`  Month as a zero-padded decimal number.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d = datetime.strptime('12/31/2015 7:00:00 PM', '%b/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')
ValueError: time data '12/31/2015 7:00:00 PM' does not match format '%b/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p'
>>> d = datetime.strptime('12/31/2015 7:00:00 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 31, 19, 0)
```

I find myself going back to this site frequently: http://strftime.org/

Or just the Python docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': {0: '12/31/2015 7:00:00 PM',
                            1: '12/31/2015 7:00:02 PM',
                            2: '12/31/2015 7:00:10 PM',
                            3: '12/31/2015 7:00:12 PM'},
                   'value': {0: 275.9271, 1: 278.559, 2: 277.5949, 3: 270.0564}})

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')

#                  time     value
# 0 2015-12-31 19:00:00  275.9271
# 1 2015-12-31 19:00:02  278.5590
# 2 2015-12-31 19:00:10  277.5949
# 3 2015-12-31 19:00:12  270.0564
```

Comment: `%H` should be replaced by `%I` as well. %H is for 24 hour clock, but this uses am/pm instead.

Comment: @HåkenLid Great point, I missed that but will update the answer now!

Comment: Remember to change the output hour from 7 to 19 as well.

Comment: @PaulFleming Glad to help!